# Saving/Updating multiple instances in mongoengine efficiently

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

Let's say I have a UI that lets the user edit multiple records from a collection and hit save.

How do I get mongoengine to save all of these records with a single call to the DB?

Currently, I am iterating over each instance and calling its `save()` method, resulting in multiple calls to the DB.

I.e.,

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

#models.py
class Foo(Document):
    bar = StringField()
    baz = StringField()

#forms.py
class FooForm(forms.form):
    bar = CharField(required=False)
    baz = CharField(required=False)
    def save():
        foo = Foo(id=self.cleaned_data['_id'][10:-2], #remove the {'$oid': '" prefix and }' ending
                bar = self.cleaned_data['bar']
                baz = self.cleaned_data['baz']
        foo.save()

#views.py
def data(request):
    FooFormSet = formset_factory(Foo, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FooFormSet(request.POST)
        for form in formset:
            if form.has_changed:
                form.save() # This results in multiple calls to the DB.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
    else:
        records = Foo.objects()
        #records.to_json() returns a json string representation
        #of an array that can be passed to the initial param
        formset = FooFormSet(initial=json.loads(records.to_json()))
        context = {'formset':formset}
        return render(request, 'data.html', context)
```

Ignore for the moment that I'm duplicating work by using the same fields in `FooForm` as I am in `Foo`. I was unable to get the `mongodbforms` to work with `ModelFormSet`s.

In the `data` method in `views.py`, I am looping over each `FooForm` in the formset, and calling `save()`, which results in multiple calls to the DB.

In the [User Guide](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/document-instances.html) for updating, it only mentions saving an individual record, not multiple records at once.

Comment: can you share some code? what have you tried?

Comment: @RafaelBarros Here is what I'm doing right now, which results in multiple calls to the DB.